# Unable to edit Selenium Webdriver Script with Jmeter

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance-testing, groovyshell

i have some problem with Jmeter, we have configured like WDS invoke the Url->it will pass the credentials to the thread groups->the threads to database->...now i need to edit WDS script as per new sprint release, now my problem is ,i am unable to edit the web driver script, i'm trying to add script, but its just invoking the driver not even getting the url,..Help me please

tried different ways like passing id,cssSelecter and xpath.

Comment: Show your code and test plan, all information that people can replicate your issue.

Comment: Thank you Lucas, while debugging i got new error please check once

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), normally it has enough information to get to the bottom of the issue. If it's not enough you can always [increase JMeter logging verbosity to DEBUG level](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) either for individual components or globally.

Also take a look at [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) (console window where you start JMeter from), the webdriver binary can log some information there as well

Comment: Hi Dimtri, Thanks for your Help , i am almost through the problem, only final stage is unable to generate HTML reports..Please go through below code and question and help me out please.  Hi Lucas, i am almost done i think, i am unable to generate Html report...Please go through below question and code ,help me out please... 
 https://stackoverflow.com/q/76624708/22089183