# Unable to Generate Html Report with Jmeter with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, groovy, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

Jmeter with Power shell is running the scripts but the end of the scripts I'm getting errors, it's not generating reports files and not creating an output folder as well, I'm running Jmeterusers.jmx file through Power Shell...

power Shell code is ...

jmeter_test.ps1

10.10.10.120

#Remove Last Test Reults
#Start-Sleep -Seconds 15600

$ResultPath = "results/testresults.jtl" if (Test-Path $ResultPath) { Remove-Item $ResultPath

for ($i = 1; $i -le 1; $i++) #9 for overnight {

## Run Tests

jmeter -nt Jmeterusers.jmx -1 results/testresults.jtl #JVM_ARGS="-Xms2g -Xmx8g" jmeter -n -t Jmeterusers.jmx -1 results/testresults.jtl #jmeter-server.bat -n -t Jmeterusers.jmx -1 results/testresults.jtl # -R 10.85.34.175,10.85.34.194,10.85.34.182,10.85.34.195

}

## Remove HTML Result Viewer Directory $OutputPath = "results/output" if (Test-Path $OutputPath) { Remove-Item $OutputPath - Recurse.

1 $FilteredPath = "results/filtered.jtl"

## Remove Last Filtered Test Results

if (Test-Path $FilteredPath) {

Remove-Item $FilteredPath

}

#C:/Users/testuser/Desktop/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/FilterResults.bat --output-file $FilteredPath --input-file $OutputPath --exclude-label-regex true -- exclude-labels "Login User." FilterResults --output-file $FilteredPath --input-file $ResultPath --exclude-label-regex true --exclude-labels "Login User."

## Generate HTML Result Viewer jmeter -g $FilteredPath -o results/output

Write-Output "Done"

**And the Below is Jmeter.Log details..**

2023-07-06 09:34:17,234 INFO o.a.j.r.d. ReportGenerator: ReportGenerator will use for Parsing the separator: ', 2023-07-06 09:34:17,234 ERROR o.a.j. JMeter: An error occurred: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot read test results file: results \filtered.jtl

at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard. ReportGenerator.(ReportGenerator.java:133) ~[Apache JMeter_core.jar:5.2.1] at org.apache.jmeter. JMeter.start(JMeter.java:542) [Apache JMeter_core.jar: 5.6]

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_261] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]

at org.apache.jmeter. NewDriver.main (NewDriver.java:259) [Apache JMeter.jar: 5.6]

**And Here is final output on power shell Screen**

FilterResults: The term 'FilterResults' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling th was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\jmeter_tests.ps1:30 char:1 FilterResults --output-file $FilteredPath --input-file $ResultPath

- CategoryInfo

: ObjectNotFound: (FilterResults: String) [], CommandNotFoundException FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

error occurred: Cannot read test results file: results\filtered.jtl errlevel=1

press any key to continue...

I tried several ways, changing/adding some of the .jar files, Changing the code in .Ps file, and so on...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 
To make it easier for others willing to help you to actually help you you should always [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) properly.
 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This bit:

> The term 'FilterResults' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

means that your (however I doubt that it's really yours) powershell script fails to locate `FilterResults.bat` file under operating system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) so the options are in:

1. Make sure that [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) is installed, if its not there - install it via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)
2. Make sure that FilterReusults.bat is in your PATH or that your current working directory is "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
3. There is no need to manually remove "old" results, if you provide [`-f` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) JMeter will overwrite the .jtl results file and the dashboard folder with the new results.
4. [According to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading.

Comment: HI,Dmitri ,Thank you for your Guidance, i am working on it , i post you further Thank You.

Comment: My problem with Jmeter resolved perfect guidance from Dmitri , Thank You .https://stackoverflow.com/a/76625624/22089183